# Class Modeling: Multiple Person, only two user system

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

In my hospital system have

- Patients
- Professionals = medical, secretary, hospital staff
- Suppliers = product suppliers
- Companies = heath plan, others

Among the four, only two can access the system: Professional (to work) and patient (To access your information)

In my financial module, everyone to contains accounts payable or receivable I need a class and information in my database, then I created my Person.cs class

And when I have a account receivable I inform PersonId for example:

```
public class Payment
{
   public AccountType Type {get;set;} //CREDIT or DEBIT
   public int PersonId {get;set;} //HERE IS PROFESSIONAL OR PATIENTS OR SUPPLIER OR COMPANY
}
```

Currently I have done

```
public class Company: Person {}
public class Patient: Person {}
public class Supplier: Person {}
public class Professional: Person {}
```

But a Patient and Professional need to access the system, so they are users of the system

I use  `asp.net identity` and can not have two classes inheriting `IdentityUser` I can't have Person: IdentityUser because the UserName property and others are required, Supplier and Company can not access the system.

I have a 3 solutions:

**Solution1** All composition(1-0/1) in Person.cs, for example:

```
public class Person
{
  //Common properties (Id, Name, Address..)
  public User User {get;set;} //for access
  public Professional Professional {get;set;}
  public Company Company {get;se;t}
  public Supplier Supplier {get;set;}
  public Patient Patient {get;set;}
}
```

**Solution 2**, Person composition in all class, for example:

```
public class Patient
{
   //patient properties specifics
   public Person Person {get;set;}
}
public class Professional 
{
   //professional properties specifics
   public Person Person {get;set;}
}
public class User:IdentityUser
{
   //user properties specifics
   public Person Person {get;set;}
}
public class Company 
{
   //company properties specifics
   public Person Person {get;set;}
}
public class Supplier
{
   //Supplier properties specifics
   public Person Person {get;set;}
}
```

**Solution 3**, User property only in Patient and Professional

```
public class User: IdentityUser {}
public class Company: Person {}
public class Patient: Person 
{
    public int? UserId {get;set;} //nullalble
}
public class Supplier: Person {}
public class Professional: Person {
    public int? UserId {get;set;} //nullalble
}
```

Each person is unique and will have two roles
A patient will only be patient, will never be professional or company. And the same for others

Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like IdentityUser and Person should not be related through inheritance. A Person is _not_ a kind of user, or vice versa. A Person may be associated with a user (Person may have an IdentityId).

Comment: @PaulHicks All inheritance Person, and IdentityId nullable in Person?

Comment: That would work. It doesn't need to be in `Person` though, it might only be in `Patient` and `Professional`. Your login functionality will be much easier to write if you look up only Patients, then Professionals if not match Patient. You could go OO and load Person, then figure out what to cast to... but why? A simple condition in login code works just as well.

Comment: @PaulHicks thanks, could evaluate your answer again from the solutions that I informed?

Comment: Your first two solutions provide `has-a` relationships instead of `is-a`. They might work but they lose some semantic value. How about implementing whatever inheritance you like *without* Identity (e.g. `Company` is-a `Person`) then have some of the classes provide an `IdentityUser` property (e.g. `Professional` has-a `IdentityUser`.

Answer (score 1):

Code attempts to model reality. Does your code reflect reality?

- Is a company a person? No.
- Is a product supplier a person? Possibly, but possibly not.
- Patients and professionals are roles that a person may fill, but they don't define a new kind of person. Humanity is made up of *people*, not of patients and professionals. Could a professional also be a patient? I don't see why not.

According to your stated business rules, only people within either the patient or professional roles may be users. A person, then, may *possibly* have a user identity and, depending on their roles, may *possibly* be able to use that identity to access the system.

```
enum Role
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Patient = 1,
    Professional = 2
}

class Person
{
    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; private set; }
    public IdentityUser User { get; private set; }
}
```

So who decides whether the person can log in? Encapsulate your business rules in a class that figures that out. As a rough example:

```
class Authenticator
{
    public bool IsAuthenticated(Person person)
    {
        if (person.User == null)
            return false;

        if (person.Roles.Any(x => x == Role.Patient || x == Role.Professional))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

And so on. Design for the reality you're attempting to model. You may also want to look into ASP.Net identity roles, as this concept is already available to you and will tie your authentication mechanisms closer to your identity (where they belong).

Comment: thanks for answering, could evaluate your answer again from the solutions that I informed?

Comment: @user98498 Your solutions confuse me. Solution 1 requires a field for all of the things that a person might have, even the things that they might not. What does it mean for a person to _have_ a company? Absolutely nothing.

Comment: Solution 2 links a Person instance to all of the classes, even the ones that make no sense. What does it mean for a Company to have a Person? It's not clear.

Comment: Solution 3 attempts to maintain the original inheritance model (which doesn't make sense) and wedge in the concept of a user ID for authentication purposes. Separate your policy (authentication) from your data (person) and _model what reality looks like._ I refer you back to the suggested model proposed in my answer.

Comment: Inheritance is a way of saying "I have a thing" and "I have a specialized kind of this thing". An Animal and a Lion, for example. A Lion is a new kind of Animal. On the other hand, you have a Person and a Professional. A Professional is not a new kind of Person, it's something that any person _could be._ Don't try to model roles with inheritance.

Comment: @Chis What about the Payment? What could receive Patient, Professional, Company or Suppliers?

Comment: @user98498 Once again, model reality. Payments are associated with invoices, not with people. Invoices may be associated with an account. A company or person may have at least one account.